# Argument Principle. Finite poles and zeros?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

This is to set up for Argument Principle.

Let $C$ be a simple closed curve and consider its region it bounds. Let $f$ be meromorphic inside $C \cup \partial C$ and analytic and nonzero on $\partial C \cup C$. The argument to show it has a finite poles goes like this.

Assume it has a sequence of infinite poles. By compactness, it has a convergent subsequence. Now my book claims the limit is just a singularity, not isolated (and therefore the number of poles is finite). Why?

**Q1:** If $p$ is the limit and I delete it $B(p,\epsilon) \setminus \{ p \}$, the other neighbouring points are still isolated singularities right? And therefore the function is analytic on this deleted neighborhood. So what is the contradiction?

**A1**: I answered my own question. The open set about the limit point is not isolated since every neighborhood about itself encloses other isolated singularities. Hence its deleted neighborhood can never be analytic.

Now apply the same to the zeroes. Take a infinite sequence, extract subsequence. If $f$ is not analytic at the limit $z_0$, then this point is an essential singularity (this leads to contradiction).

**Q2**: Is this because the non analytic point $z_0$ must be a singularity and since we assumed they must be poles, it must categorized into one of the three known singularities.

Now it can't be removable, otherwise we have analytic continuation

Now why can't it be a pole of order $k$?

This is taken reference from Saff/Snider page 356.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/939876/limit-point-of-zero-points-implying-a-zero-function for half of this.

Comment: @EricTowers I don't get it how does it answer the second question?

Comment: at a pole the function goes to infinity in absolute values so it cannot have zeroes nearby

Comment: @Conrad ah okay and so the possibilities are eliminated leaving essential singularity as the last choice.